# Parsing HttpResponse into customized object

Tags: java, json

I'm using some weather api that returns actual forecast for given city. 
I would like to parse `HtmlResponse` into my object which looks like this:

```
public class Weather {

    String countryCode;
    String city;
    double temperature;
    double sensedTemperature;
    int humidity;
    int windSpeed; // meter/sec
    int windDirection;
    int pressure;
    int weatherDescription;
}
```

Method that does whole operations:

```
@GetMapping("/weather")
    public void getCurrentWeather(@RequestParam String city, @RequestParam(required = false) String lang,
                                  @RequestParam(required = false) String units)
            throws UnirestException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        //Params
        String query = getQueryAccordingToGivenParameters(city, lang, units);

        HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get(HOST + "?" + query)
                .header("x-rapidapi-host", X_RAPID_HOST)
                .header("x-rapidapi-key", X_RAPIDAPI_KEY)
                .asJson();

        System.out.println(response.getBody());
    }
```

Right now it prints response in command line, but I would like to convert it to `Weather` object.

JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "visibility": 10000,
  "timezone": 0,
  "main": {
    "temp": 7.21,
    "temp_min": 5.56,
    "humidity": 81,
    "pressure": 1029,
    "feels_like": 4.87,
    "temp_max": 9
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 75
  },
  "sys": {
    "country": "GB",
    "sunrise": 1577433953,
    "sunset": 1577462200,
    "id": 1414,
    "type": 1
  },
  "dt": 1577444681,
  "coord": {
    "lon": -0.13,
    "lat": 51.51
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "icon": "04d",
      "description": "broken clouds",
      "main": "Clouds",
      "id": 803
    }
  ],
  "name": "London",
  "cod": 200,
  "id": 2643743,
  "base": "stations",
  "wind": {
    "speed": 1.5
  }
}
```

I need 
"name" - london, 
"wind" - speed - 1.5
"weather" - description - "broken clouds"
"main" - temp - 7.21
"main" - humidity - 81 
and some others but these are just examples.

I tried to use `JSONObject` and get wind speed like this:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONObject windObject = new JSONObject(object);
        String wind = windObject.getString("wind");
        System.out.println(wind);
```

but I got `org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["wind"] not found.`
Could you tell me how to fetch the speed of the wind and how to fetch description weather? The rest I should do by my own.

//within Andreas answer code looks like this:

```
package weatherapp;

import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

@RestController
public class WeatherController {

    public static final String X_RAPID_HOST = "community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com";
    public static final String X_RAPIDAPI_KEY = "...";
    public static final String CHARSET = "UTF-8";
    public static final String HOST = "https://community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com/weather";

    //{city}/{lang}/{units]
    @GetMapping("/weather")
    public void getCurrentWeather(@RequestParam String city, @RequestParam(required = false) String lang,
                                     @RequestParam(required = false) String units)
            throws UnirestException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        //Params
        String query = getQueryAccordingToGivenParameters(city, lang, units);

        HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get(HOST + "?" + query)
                .header("x-rapidapi-host", X_RAPID_HOST)
                .header("x-rapidapi-key", X_RAPIDAPI_KEY)
                .asJson();

        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONObject wind = root.getJSONObject("wind");
        double windSpeed = wind.getDouble("speed");
        System.out.println(windSpeed);
    }

    ...
}
```

but it throws:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["wind"] not found.] with root cause

org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["wind"] not found.
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:471) ~[json-20160212.jar:na]
    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:636) ~[json-20160212.jar:na]
    at weatherapp.WeatherController.getCurrentWeather(WeatherController.java:42) ~[classes/:na]

...
```

After debugging root looks like this:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Which JSON library are you using? `JSONObject` could be [`org.json.JSONObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject) (Android), [`org.json.JSONObject`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html) (JSON-java), [`net.sf.json.JSONObject`](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html) (Json-lib), [`processing.data.JSONObject`](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/data/JSONObject.html), ...

Comment: @Andreas import org.json.JSONObject;

Comment: Why are you calling the [`JSONObject(Object bean)`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject-java.lang.Object-) constructor with a `JSONObject` object in line 2? --- Why are you calling `getString("wind")` when the `wind` field is a JSON Object, as indicated by the `{` after the `:`?

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, I got it now and your answer looks logical and should work, but it does not :/

Comment: What is `JsonNode`? If the `Unirest` API has already parsed the JSON into objects, why are you trying to use another JSON API? Use the one you already have.

Comment: @Andreas yup. I have answered my question with proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

***UPDATED***

It really helps when you **read the documentation** of the API you're using. Providing relevant links to javadoc below!!!

Since `response` is an [`HttpResponse<JsonNode>`](http://javadox.com/com.mashape.unirest/unirest-java/1.4.5/com/mashape/unirest/http/HttpResponse.html) object, you need to call [`getBody()`](http://javadox.com/com.mashape.unirest/unirest-java/1.4.5/com/mashape/unirest/http/HttpResponse.html#getBody--) to get the body of the response, call [`getObject()`](http://javadox.com/com.mashape.unirest/unirest-java/1.4.5/com/mashape/unirest/http/JsonNode.html#getObject--) on the ***already parsed*** [`JsonNode`](http://javadox.com/com.mashape.unirest/unirest-java/1.4.5/com/mashape/unirest/http/JsonNode.html) object to get the root [`JSONObject`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html) object, call [`getJSONObject`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject-java.lang.String-) to get the nested `wind` object, and finally call [`getDouble`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#getDouble-java.lang.String-) to get the `speed` value.

```
JsonNode rootNode = response.getBody();
JSONObject rootObj = rootNode.getObject();
JSONObject windObj = rootObj.getJSONObject("wind");
double windSpeed = windObj.getDouble("speed");
```

Comment: It does not work. I have updated question with your answer.

Comment: I have added root after debugging to question.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch wind speed with:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject wind = json.getJSONObject("wind");
double speed = wind.getDouble("speed");
```

And the weather description as follows:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject weather = json.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0);
String description = weather.getString("description");
```

Answer (score 0):

your json output shows that "wind" key is an object and you are trying to get wind as string.

Use this

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONObject windObject = object.getJSONObject("wind");
        String speed = windObject.getString("speed");
        System.out.println(speed);
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this:

```
 HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get(HOST + "?" + query)
                .header("x-rapidapi-host", X_RAPID_HOST)
                .header("x-rapidapi-key", X_RAPIDAPI_KEY)
                .asJson();

       JSONObject z = response.getBody().getObject();
       JSONObject zz = z.getJSONObject("wind");
       double wind = zz.getDouble("speed");
```